# Necesito calcular el coeficiente de correlación de datos ... ERROR

Tags: python, scipy

Estoy tratando de hacer un análisis de series temporales  al intentar calcular el coeficiente de correlación sale un error al parecer de concatenación, puede ayudarme a entender que pasa??

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import linregress
#reading data from a web
data = pd.read_csv('http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~shumway/globtemp.dat')
x=data[44:142]
t = np.arange(1900,1997,1)
a, b = np.polyfit(t, x, 1)
linregress(t, x)

----------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-55-ee41cc47761d> in <module>()
 14 # Calculamos el coeficiente de correlación
 15 #r = np.corrcoef(t, x)
 ---> 16 linregress(t, x)
 17 # Dibujamos los datos para poder visualizarlos y ver si sería lógico
 18 # considerar el ajuste usando un modelo lineal

 /anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/stats/_stats_mstats_common.py in linregress(x, y)
 77 
 78     # average sum of squares:
 ---> 79     ssxm, ssxym, ssyxm, ssym = np.cov(x, y, bias=1).flat
 80     r_num = ssxym
 81     r_den = np.sqrt(ssxm * ssym)

 /Users/.../anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/lib/function_base.py in cov(m, y, rowvar, bias, ddof, fweights, aweights)
 2430         if rowvar == 0 and y.shape[0] != 1:
 2431             y = y.T
 -> 2432         X = np.vstack((X, y))
 2433 
 2434     if ddof is None:

/Users/../anaconda/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/shape_base.py in vstack(tup)
228 
229     """
--> 230     return _nx.concatenate([atleast_2d(_m) for _m in tup], 0)
231 
232 def hstack(tup):
```

Se muestra el siguiente error...

```
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scipy.stats.linregress` acepta, como muchas otras funciones o métodos de **SciPy**, objetos "array-like". Tanto los dataframes como las series de **Pandas** lo son, no obstante le estas pasando un dataframe (`x`) y a la hora de iterar sobre el no sabe sobre que columna actuar (aunque solo tiene una en este caso). La solución es **especificar la columna de forma explícita** sobre la que aplicar `linregress`:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy.stats import linregress

data = pd.read_csv('http://anson.ucdavis.edu/~shumway/globtemp.dat')
x=data[44:142]
t = np.arange(1900,1997,1)
linregress(t, x.ix[:,0])  #<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

También puedes usar el nombre de la columna, en tu caso se llama '-.36' puedes hacer simplemente:

```
linregress(t, x['-.36'])
```

La salida es:

> ```
> LinregressResult(slope=0.0063759730696402277,
>                  intercept=-12.507199663370503,
>                  rvalue=0.81632615171153833,
>                  pvalue=2.2480862682626864e-24,
>                  stderr=0.00046285135807816143
>                 )
> ```

Comment: Gracias.... super